# fill NaN values in pandas series with selected values randomly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series with null value:

```
    cola
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
```

I want to fill those `NaN` values such that `60%` of rows contains `2` and remaining `50%` contains `8` randomly.

Desired Output:

```
    cola
0    2
1    8
2    8
3    2
......
```

One more question. I have few categorical columns like `gender` `married` with `NaN` values in my pandas dataframe and I am trying to do a classfication prediction task.

What are the best ways for finding values to fill in those `NaN`. For numerical column I usually place `mean` of that column in the `NaN` rows.

Comment: `df.cola = np.random.choice([2, 8], len(df))`

Comment: @user3483203 That seems to do the trick. Thank you :).

Comment: @user3483203 Is there a way I could fill them for example 60% data with 2 and remaining 40% data with 8 randomly? I'll update the question.

Comment: You can use probability for non-uniform distribution, np.random.choice([2, 8], len(df), p=[0.6, 0.4])

Comment: @Vaishali Thank you so much :)